# Donwload a specific blob (Azure) from multiples containers with python

Tags: python, azure, containers, blob

I'm jus lookin for some help. I'm very newed on python but i try to do something. I need to download a specific blob (actually is a .xlsx file) from multiples containers. I mean, the process create a container dayly but what interests me is to download a single file from each container and I've tried the following:

```
# download_blobs.py
# Python program to bulk download blob files from azure storage
# Uses latest python SDK() for Azure blob storage
# Requires python 3.6 or above
import os
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient
from azure.storage.blob import ContentSettings, ContainerClient
 
# IMPORTANT: Replace connection string with your storage account connection string
# Usually starts with DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;...
MY_CONNECTION_STRING = "my_conection_string"
 
# Replace with blob container
MY_BLOB_CONTAINER = "^092022"
 
# Replace with the local folder where you want files to be downloaded
LOCAL_BLOB_PATH = "a_local_path"

# Replace with the blob to download

BLOB_NAME = "^xlsx'"

class AzureBlobFileDownloader:
  def __init__(self):
    print("Intializing AzureBlobFileDownloader")
 
    # Initialize the connection to Azure storage account
    self.blob_service_client =  BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(MY_CONNECTION_STRING)
    self.my_container = self.blob_service_client.get_container_client(MY_BLOB_CONTAINER)
 
 
  def save_blob(self,file_name,file_content):
    # Get full path to the file
    download_file_path = os.path.join(LOCAL_BLOB_PATH, file_name)
 
    # for nested blobs, create local path as well!
    os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(download_file_path), exist_ok=True)
 
    with open(download_file_path, "wb") as file:
      file.write(file_content)
 
  def download_all_blobs_in_container(self):

    my_blobs = self.my_container.list_blobs(BLOB_NAME)
    for blob in my_blobs:
      print(blob.name)
      bytes = self.my_container.get_blob_client(blob).download_blob().readall()
      self.save_blob(blob.name, bytes)
 
# Initialize class and upload files
azure_blob_file_downloader = AzureBlobFileDownloader()
azure_blob_file_downloader.download_all_blobs_in_container()
```

Each container created dayly has te following name:

01092022 -
02092022 -
03092022 -
.
.
.

and the blob that I want to download is:

p.01092022.xlsx -
p.02092022.xlsx -
p.03092022.xlsx -
.
.
.

How can I make to python go through each container and download the file related to each one according to the sequence of names they have?

Thanks for you help!

Greatings.

Answer (score 0):

Does it create only 1 container with 1 file per day?
Always following that pattern? (01092022 - 02092022 - 03092022)

Regarding "How can I make to python go through each container and download the file related to each one according to the sequence of names they have?"
If you stick with the name convention you could use something like this:

```
containers = blob_service_client_instance.list_containers() 
for c in containers:    
    blob_name = 'p.' + c.name + ".xlsx"    
    blob_client_instance = blob_service_client_instance.get_blob_client(c.name, blob_name, snapshot=None)
    exists = blob_client_instance.exists()
    if exists == True:
        blob_data = blob_client_instance.download_blob()
        data = blob_data.readall()
```

but that would start becoming a long run after a while. You may want to add a line to search a range, like last 6 months

Comment: - for the first: Yes, the process create just 1 container per day, but with diffrents files (incluided file audios). i'm interested only on .xlsx files. 

- the process beging on january, so i have to download all the xlsx files since then. but after all, just need the file of the day in course.